# New to regex -- unexpected results in for loop

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I'm not sure if this is a problem in my understanding of regex modules, or a silly mistake I'm making in my for loop.

I have a list of numbers that look like this:

```
4; 94
3; 92
1; 53
```

etc.

I made a regex pattern to match just the last two digits of the string:

```
'^.*\s([0-9]+)$'
```

This works when I take each element of the list 1 at a time.

However when I try and make a for loop

```
for i in xData:
    if re.findall('^.*\s([0-9]+)$', i)
       print i
```

The output is simply the entire string instead of just the last two digits.

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here but if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code when you took each element of the list one at a time.

Comment: What's `xData`?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are printing `i`, the whole string. You are not printing the return value of `re.findall()`.

Comment: You are printing the entire string, to print the match do `re.findall(_____)[0]`

Comment: The `^.*` in `'^.*\s([0-9]+)$'` is not necessary. Just do `\s([0-9]+)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the whole string, `i`. If you wanted to print the output of `re.findall()`, then store the result and print *that result*:

```
for i in xData:
    results = re.findall('^.*\s([0-9]+)$', i)
    if results:
        print results
```

I don't think that `re.findall()` is the right method here, since your lines contain just the one set of digits. Use `re.search()` to get a match object, and if the match object is not `None`, take the first group data:

```
for i in xData:
    match = re.search('^.*\s([0-9]+)$', i)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
```

Comment: Yup that was the issue, feel a little slow but thanks for the quick response !

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, but if all you're looking to do is get the last 2 characters, could you use the below?

```
for i in xData:
    print(i[-2:])
```

Comment: The OP's example only has 2 digits but the regex will get any number of trailing digits. A better Python only approach would be `i.split()[-1]` since there is a space separator in there.